# How to completely kill NGINX in windows?

Tags: nginx

Eventhough i killed the nginx process still it is running ..

I did the following steps
1)Finding the process PID using `netstat -n -a -o | findstr "0.0.0.0:80"` and killing it with `taskkill /F /PID 52544`
2)Even i tried giving `taskkill /F /IM nginx.exe` in command prompt

Now when i use `netstat -n -a -o | findstr "0.0.0.0:80"` i dont see any process running on port 80 but still i can see the nginx homepage in port 80?

I dont know how to stop that process

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just stop nginx's service?

Comment: yeah i tried that one too.It is throwing error like this `failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: Is it maybe cached? Ctrl+F8

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with browser since it is using autofill option . When i unchecked autofill and cleared the cache now i can see nginx is stopped.

Answer (score 12):

Use `nginx -s stop` to stop all nginx processes

Comment: You'll have to navigate to the folder where NGINX is installed first and then the above command `nginx -s stop` shown by Endogen will work.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the code `taskkill /f /IM nginx.exe` in `cmd` for removing all the running nginx process in windows

Or use `nginx -s stop`

Comment: worked where the other answers failed

Comment: taskkill worked.  but nginx -s stop not working for me.

Answer (score 7):

**First Way (Manually):**

Know the `/PID` by Command: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq nginx.exe"` and `taskkill /f /pid *pid of nginx.exe*`.

**Second Way (Pragmatically):**

If you want to terminate with batch script (save as `nginx_terminator.bat`):

```
@echo off
::===============================
::=======NGINX TERMINATER========
::===============================
::[Author:WinPhay Date:8.29.2017]
::===============================
:LOOP
tasklist | find /i "nginx.exe">nul  && Taskkill /F /IM  "nginx.exe" & exit/b
timeout /t 30
goto:LOOP
```

For more information read the [Nginx for Windows](https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) documentation.

Comment: I had everything of the command: `tasklist | find /i "nginx.exe">nul  && Taskkill /F /IM  "nginx.exe"` but not the `& exit/b timeout /t 30 goto:LOOP`. I am surprised without the second part of `& exit/b timeout /t 30 goto:LOOP` the nginx process was restarting again and again. What was the reason of such a restart of all nginx master and worker